# How to "deepcopy" Python object skipping one or more attributes?

Tags: python, object, deep-copy

I'm trying to create a simple deepcopy function that simply skipps some object attributes, but my prototype implementation below goes into infinite recursion. Is this the right way to proceed?

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.copied = 1
        self.skipped = 2

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        obj = type(self)()
        for attr in dir(self):
            if attr in ['skipped']:
                continue
            attr_copy = deepcopy(getattr(self, attr), memo)
            setattr(obj, attr, attr_copy)
            pass
        return obj

o1 = Foo()
o2 = deepcopy(o1)
```

(I'm aware in this simple case I can just use delattr on a new instance, but for more complex cases I would like to use the deepcopy functionality.)

Comment: I think the problem is that what you want isn't actually simple. E.g. because you use `obj = type(self)()` your code won't work if `Foo` needs some parameter for `__init__()` other than `self`. You should examine the (python) source code of the `copy` module; it's in your python installation `Lib` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best or proper approach, but I finally came up with the following:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    cls = self.__class__
    obj = cls.__new__(cls)
    memo[id(self)] = obj
    for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
        if k == ['skipped']:
            v = dict()
        setattr(obj, k, deepcopy(v, memo))
        pass
    return obj
```